# editText command on my first app Google

Tags: android, eclipse, function

I'm trying to be a Google developer, actually I'm in my first app.
I'm doing exactly Google Development shows, but I'm have a editText error, and I don't understand why. 
This is my code:

```
   package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public final static String  EXTRA_MESSAGE= "com.example.myfirtapp.MESSAGE";

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button
 * 
 * @param view
 */
public void sendMessage (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.edit_text);
    String message= editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);


 }  // Do something in response to button
```

I'm having a problem with

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById (r.id.edit_message)
```

Please help me

Comment: you didnt include the error in your question.

Comment: r should be R... and you miss ";"